# Combine Two Perl Scripts

Tags: regex, perl

At this point, I am using two perl scripts to convert a text file into the format I want. One perl script downloads a file off the web using API, stores it as a file, then prints only the IP addresses (e.g. ips.txt) - I then direct the output into another text file (e.g. perl script1.pl > ips2.txt). The printed output looks like this:

```
222.187.221.224
222.187.221.250
222.187.239.35
222.187.239.136
222.215.230.79
222.215.230.85
```

The second script takes the file I created to change the IPs into the following format:

```
("222.187.239.35" OR "222.187.239.136" OR "222.215.230.79" OR "222.215.230.85")
```

My question is, how do I most efficiently combine these two perl scripts into one to perform all required actions? The file creations are unnecessary, it's just the only way I figured out how to do it so far. Help is greatly appreciated.

**First script:**

```
#/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use Regexp::Common qw/net/;

getstore("https://<redacted>", "ips.txt");


open(my $input, "<", "ips.txt");

while (<$input>) {
    print $1, "\n" if /($RE{net}{IPv4})/;
}
```

**Second script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use Regexp::Common qw/net/;

open(my $input, "<", "ips2.txt");

print '(', join(' OR ', map { chomp; qq{"$_"} } grep { /$RE{net}{IPv4}/ } <$input>), ")\n";
```

**Desired printed output (many more IPs, this is just an example):**

```
("222.187.239.35" OR "222.187.239.136" OR "222.215.230.79" OR "222.215.230.85")
```

Comment: That `grep { /$RE{net}{IPv4}/ }` is unnecessary based on how you populate the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use LWP::UserAgent qw( );
use Regexp::Common qw( net );

# Obviously incomplete, but good enough for IP addresses.
sub text_to_lit {
   my ($s) = @_;
   return qq{"$s"};
}

my $url = 'https://...';

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $ua->get($url);
$response->is_success()
   or die("Can't download $url: " . $response->status_line() . "\n");

my $content = $response->content();

my @ips = $content =~ /^.*?($RE{net}{IPv4})/mg;   # First per line
   -or-
my @ips = $content =~ /$RE{net}{IPv4}/g;          # All of them

print "(".( join " OR ", map text_to_lit($_), @ips ).")\n";
```